# ¿Cómo condicionar una fila 'Null' en MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

¡Hola amigos! presento un pequeño problema y es el siguiente:

Quiero condicionar **una fila 'Null'** en MySql pero no se como hacerlo. 
Este es mi código PHP:

```
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    $resultados = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * from usuarios where numero is null AND id = idUsuario");


    if($resultados= Null){
        require 'need_phone.php';
    }else{
        require 'have_phone.php';
    }
```

Lo que quiero es que si la fila es '**Null**' me traiga el archivo "**need_phone.php**" de lo contrario me traiga el archivo "**have_phone.php**"

¡De antemano se los agradezco!

Comment: Es que estas ocupando el operador de comparación incorrecto, si usas **=** es asignación; es decir a = 10, en cambio para comparar es así **===**

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar, pero no me sirve, no me lee la condición. Se supone que debería redirigir a "have_phone.php" pero no lo hizo, sigue eligiendo el archivo "need_phone.php"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código creo que podría modificarse ligeramente para tratar mejor al resultado de tipo `mysqli_result`.

```
  $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
  $resultados = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * from usuarios where numero is null AND id = idUsuario");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($resultados) > 0){ // <-- Ajuste aquí 
    require 'need_phone.php';
  } else {
    require 'have_phone.php';
  }
```

Nota que el resultado de la consulta no sería `null` como se asume en el código original puesto que ese método retorna uno de los siguientes valores según [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

- `FALSE`: Ante un error.
- Objeto de tipo `mysqli_result`: Para consultas satisfactorias de los tipos SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN.
- `TRUE`: Para otras consultas satisfactorias.

Answer (score 2):

Aparte del error de sintaxis mencionado.

Me parece que sería mas sencillo si lo manejas de este modo:

- Haces una consulta usando una función de agregación; en este caso `COUNT` que devolverá un número mayor o igual a 0 dependiendo si se encuentra al menos un registro con dichas condiciones
- Usamos la función `mysqli_num_rows()` para obtener el número que nos devolvió la consulta anterior
- Dentro dle `if` verificamos si el valor que nos devolvió es 0, en dicho caso es que no existe un registro y *requerimos* el archivo `need_phone.php` o en caso contrario el archivo `have_phone.php`

Código

```
<?php 

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

$resultados = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                    from usuarios 
                                    where numero is null 
                                    AND id = idUsuario");

$conteoFilas = mysqli_num_rows($resultados);

if ($conteoFilas == 0)
{
    require 'need_phone.php';
} else {
    require 'have_phone.php';
}
```

**¿Por qué el cambio en la estructura del código?**

Bueno tu estás tratando de comparar el *resultado de la consulta* como que si si tiene resultados los devuelve y si no encuentra registros genera `NULL` lo cual no es así; de hecho.

Si imprimes la consulta de forma directa así:

```
echo $resultados;
```

Obtendrás un resultado como este:

> PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not
>   be converted to string

Por eso no obtienes el comportamiento esperado, ya que como el resultado en tu condicional no da `NULL` entonces se pasa al bloque de código del `ELSE`

Answer (score 2):

El codigo seria de la siguiente manera si quisieras comparar y saber si es null.

```
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    $resultados = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * from usuarios where numero is null AND id = idUsuario");

    if($resultados== Null){
        require 'need_phone.php';
    }else{
        require 'have_phone.php';
    }
```